# Can I use a breakpoint in a notification listener of a GarbageCollectorMXBean

Tags: java, debugging, garbage-collection

I have registered notification listeners to the GarbageCollectorMXBeans.  I can see that they work, because they log but I want to understand why I cannot debug them, i.e., a breakpoint in my notification listener is not hit.

The log tells me that the listener is called on a thread called "Service Thread".  This thread does not show if I look at all the threads running, so I assume it is a private Jvm thread of some sort.  Is it possible to debug this thread with breakpoints?

Comment: I think the answer is no.